# Application security training for developers

Tags: appsec, professional-education, owasp, waf

I am trying to establish an application security group within an organization and although there is a plethora of courses for penetration testers, i fail to find an equal amount of training courses for developers / QA testers

The team i work with is very capable when it comes to its core functions (development, testing, testing automation) but have very limited exposure to application security - very basic knowledge of the OWASP Top 10

I looked on the Internet for courses to help them build their knowledge, and so far i have found 2-3 courses from SANS and a training bundle from Aspect Security. I haven't tried any of these yet, since i wanted to get some opinions before we commit

The ideal course(s) should contain:

- An introduction, ideally based on the OWASP Top 10
- Defensive techniques, ideally presented as a framework (e.g. OWASP ESAPI)
- Security testing, oriented towards QA testers who like to automate vs manual penetration testing
- Application of WAFs (for virtual patching)

Do you know of any course bundle that can provide me with this content, or should i be looking for individual courses from different providers? And if so, can you provide me with the names of training providers that you have used and you are satisfied with?

Comment: haha, "virtual patching",  do you also call it getting "virtual pwn3d" when your waf is bypassed?

Comment: There are external security consultant companies out there that provide training tailor made to your specifications. But I am not sure if naming them here would be appropriate, since I myself have been associated with one of them

Comment: Secure coding *is* one of a development team's core functions.

Comment: Unfortunately, this feels a lot like a shopping question which, for better or for worse, is rather verboten on StackExchange sites.

Answer (score 9):

There's a couple of free resources I know about which could be good introductions for this kind of thing.  Security Innovations have a free [OWASP top 10 CBT](https://owasp.teammentor.net/teamMentor), Security compass have something similar [here](http://securitycompass.com/computer-based-training/#!/get-free-owasp-course) as do [Trustwave](https://www.trustwave.com/sae_sample/owasp-top-10/Start.htm)

Beyond these basic ones at least two of those companies will have more options that are pay for, but these ones could be a good, free, starting point.

Comment: Thanks, both the Trustwave link and the OWASP CBT seem extremely useful!

Answer (score 3):

I recommend looking at Microsoft's Security Development Lifecycle (SDL).  They have a lot of great resources.

Also look at BSIMM and OpenSAMM.

Some related questions and information:

- [Secure Software Development](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/9007/971)
- [Reading about security by design?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/7457/971)
- [How and where to begin on the Return of Web Application Security Investment?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/11927/971)
- [What is considered the simplest (or lightest) secure development lifecycle?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/624/971)
- [I am looking for feedback on Secure Development Lifecycle for Scrum that has been tested?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/689/971)

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Safelight Security](http://safelightsecurity.com).  They are focused on application security training have an entire curriculum for developers.  Full disclosure - I work for Safelight!  If you want to get information, you can request it directly from Larry Gorkun lgorkun@safelightsecurity.com.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Codebashing](http://www.codebashing.com) and their [sql injection demo](http://www.codebashing.com/sql_demo).

They have developed a cloud hosted application security training platform that offers interactive tutorials which also lets developers/students test security issues using sandboxed war games. Very similar to Codeacademy but for application security.

Full Disclosure - I am a content developer at www.codebashing.com

Answer (score -1):

Denim Group also does application security training, both through e-training and instructor led onsite classes....I've take the classes, they're pretty good.